# Azure Internal Load Balancer - Private DNS?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-load-balancer, internal-load-balancer, azure-dns

I know with external load balancers in azure we can assign a DNS, but can the same be achieved with an internal load balancer? Using MS Private DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, it's **not** possible.

Azure private DNS only works for Azure VM.

You could give your feedback to this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback), all of the feedback you share in this link will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the answer - so in the case of Azure Container Services, where internal services can be exposed via an internal load balancer, it must be expected that services consuming containers via the load balancer are expected to request it by IP Address rather than with a DNS???

Comment: @watdo  That is not same as Azure private DNS,  there is a service running in ACS works like DNS, not Azure private DNS.

Comment: Yep - for components internal to the cluster running off kube-dns is perfectly fine and works well, but exposing services inside the microservices cluster to azure app services within an app service environment privately? I haven't seen a way of using kube-dns for that yet, so assumed we could expose these via an ILB annotated service - and again this seems to work, but means you have to communicate via IP which seems limiting if it ever changes. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @watdo Sorry for the delay, you are right, we can't use private in this way, maybe we can use IP address, just keep that service running, and do not delete that service, that IP address will not change, even re-create pods.